# Prevent dafault action in Jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm working on project which is using [Jquery Tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/). My tabs have links. One of them is to ids on this page which enable to show specific hidden element,

```
<a href="#rings">Rings</a>
```

and one of them is just simple links to another page,

```
<a href="/amulets">Amulets</a>
```

Here is how they are creating:

```
$('.b-head-nav-tabs').parent().tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    show: { effect: 'slideDown', duration: 300 },
    hide: { effect: 'slideUp', duration: 100 }
});
```

And I need to prevent default tabs action and enable user to go to the specific link if he clicks on it bypassing all Jquery Tabs magic. I tried to make specific tabs disabled like that,

```
var disabledTabsString = $('.disabled-tabs').text();
var disabledTabsArray  = disabledTabsString.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < disabledTabsArray.length; i++) {
    disabledTabsArray[i] = parseInt(disabledTabsArray[i]);
}
...
disabled: disabledTabsArray,
```

But it makes specific tabs disabled even if they have links to go. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your html structure look like for the tabs?

Comment: @Twisty, I've tried to make tab disabled. I thought it will be disabled just for js, but it makes tabs disabled even if you click on link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to add `data-url` property to specific urls which I want to go directly. And then I'm using `beforeActivate` method to check if there `data-url` and then redirect user to this link.

```
$('.b-head-nav-tabs').parent().tabs({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        show: { effect: 'slideDown', duration: 300 },
        hide: { effect: 'slideUp', duration: 100 },
        beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
            var url = $('a', ui.newTab).attr('data-url');
            if (url != undefined) {
                document.location = url;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```